# How to convert saved model to tflite file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I want to use model from this project https://github.com/mrahtz/tensorflow-pos-tagger and convert it to tflite file so I could use it in Android app.

After I generated checkpoint files (data, index and meta files) I tried to convert them to .pbtxt file with this script.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--checkpoint', type=str,
                        dest='checkpoint',
                        help='dir or .ckpt file to load checkpoint from',
                        metavar='CHECKPOINT', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--model', type=str,
                        dest='model',
                        help='.meta for your model',
                        metavar='MODEL', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--out-path', type=str,
                        dest='out_path',
                        help='model output directory',
                        metavar='MODEL_OUT', required=True)
    opts = parser.parse_args()
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(opts.model)
    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(opts.out_path)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # Restore variables from disk.
        saver.restore(sess, opts.checkpoint)
        print("Model restored.")
        builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,
                                       [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                                       strip_default_attrs=False)
        builder.save(as_text=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After I executed this command in terminal

```
python export.py --checkpoint model.ckpt --model model.ckpt.meta --out-path ./export
```

I got another folder in project named export that contains variables folder and saved_model.pbtxt.

Then I used this command:

```
tflite_convert --output_file=test.tflite --saved_model_dir=D:\Praksa-local\tensorflow-pos-tagger-master\export
```

and I get the following error:

ValueError: No 'serving_default' in the SavedModel's SignatureDefs. Possible values are ''.

Does anyone know a proper way to do this? I am having a lot of trouble finding the right answer.